# Redirect to the parent window in Spring MVC Contorller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, popup

I am working on a Spring MVC application. I have a situation where i am submitting the information from the pop up. How do i write the redirect in the controller so that i will redirect to the parent page from where the popup is submitted.

from the pop up i am going to the below controller. From there i want to come to the parent window. I am not sure how can i achieve this. 
For Example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(Value="/home", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public ModelAndView homepAge(@ModelAttribute("homeForm") HomeForm homeForm, BindingResult errors,
        HttpServletResponse response,HttpServletRequest requst) {

...
return mnv; //here i want to go to the same page from where i came from
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to redirect to the referring URL, try something like this...

```
@RequestMapping(value="/home", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public ModelAndView homepAge(@ModelAttribute("homeForm") HomeForm homeForm, BindingResult errors,
                             HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    String referer = request.getHeader("referer");
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + referer, model);
}
```

Comment: @laneMaxwell Hi I have tried this, But i got an exception stating that:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed  org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:483)

Can you please provide a solution.

Comment: Check my edits, which should account for the referring url and use spring mvc for performing the redirect.

Comment: is model mandatory in this? or it can be:  return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + referer); ? @lane.Maxwell

Answer (score 0):

you can use this example :

```
    @RequestMapping(Value="/home", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView homepAge(@ModelAttribute("homeForm") HomeForm homeForm, BindingResult errors,
            HttpServletResponse response,HttpServletRequest requst) {


    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/myURL");

}
```

Comment: Hi. I have tried this but i got 404 as the url is different than what i expected. Url is coming as the data in popup as params in the url. But i need the parent window url i.e the referrer basically as lane.maxwell suggested but that gave me an error too :( @hichamAbdedaime

Comment: i'm sorry , I did not understand the question ,see this url a similair question

Comment: i dont see any url in the above comment .Can you please add the url

Comment: Hi. Thnaks a lot for your response. Lane.Maxwell's suggestion worked out.

Comment: ok this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804581/spring-mvc-controller-redirect-to-previous-page